# Create new columns based on date and month in rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If i have a dataframe with row-wise information on disputes unique for each ID, how do i create a new column and have data for each month and year combination. The below is just an example, I could easily just duplicate teh column and rename but that isn't the point. I provided a data table for logic purposes.

```
ID#   Month   Year    Dispute_Count    Dispute_Amount
1234  5       2020    1                100 
1234  6       2020    2                400 
...
```

```
ID#   Month   Year    Dispute_Count    Dispute_Amount   May_2020_Disputes   May_2020_Dispute_Amount                             
1234  5       2020    1                100              1                   100
1234  6       2020    2                400              2                   400

...
```

Comment: Something like `df = df.groupby(by=['Year', 'Month'], axis=0)`.

Comment: shouldn't the second row for `May_2020_Disputes` be `1` and for `May_2020_Dispute_Amount` be `100`?